# Openstack ussuri Openrc file content

Tags: openstack

I would like to create an openrc file for all my horizon users (admin, normal user, ...) so that i can scope in cmd and execute openstack commands that interact directly with Horizon Dashboard. The issue is that i'm not sure about the right content of openrc file for example (admin-openrc.sh) which contains in my case:

```
export OS_USERNAME=admin
export OS_PASSWORD=openstack
export OS_PROJECT_NAME=admin
export OS_USER_DOMAIN_NAME=Default
export OS_PROJECT_DOMAIN_NAME=Default
export OS_AUTH_URL=http://10.0.0.11:35357/v3 (example of controller IP)
export OS_IDENTITY_API_VERSION=2
export OS_IMAGE_API_VERSION=3
```

My issue is that i don't understand which URL should be used in the release Ussuri of openstack in the line :

export OS_AUTH_URL=http://10.0.0.11:35357/v3 (example of controller IP)
I'm supposing that the remain 7 lines are correct.

If anyone can help me to understand, it will be very helpful for me.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The auth_url is your keystone endpoint since keystone is the authentication service. You can verify by running `openstack endpoint list | grep keystone`. Just one note: the port 35357 is deprecated, usually all endpoints use port 5000.
You can also download a current openrc file via horizon dashboard and compare. But the basic structure is the same. Can you clarify why you compare Newton vs. Ussuri? Are these two different environments or did you upgrade N to U? I thought this was a new installation.

Comment: Hi eblock, thank you for your feedback. Is this structure of openrc file for Openstack Ussuri is still valid and working or not ? Because the endpoint format for keystone service is different than Newton release for example ...  Any clarification is welcome. Thanks.

Comment: Hi eblock, thanks for your answer. So i would like to create openrc file for each user as you know. If i download the openrc file from Horizon and copy the same content in the openrc file in command line, the question is if it will work or not ? For example if i copy the openrc file content from horizon for admin user to the openrc file for admin in command line, should i change some lines or should i keep the same content like found in openrc file in Horizon ? I hope that you understand what i mean. My final goal is to be able to execute openstack commands in CMD and find result in Horizon.

Comment: You see the content of the openrc file, if you want to customize it for individual users you need to change the user specific parameters like username, password, etc. This is pretty self-explanatory, I believe. The rest (AUTH_URL, IMAGE_API, IDENTITY_VERSION) you can keep, of course. And then test the access, you'll see if it works.

Comment: I agree but the URL is the parameter that troubles me because it varies from one release to another I think. I'm going to test but I won't have time because I'm going to take the COA exam and time is limited.

Comment: The url has always been the controller ip or rather fqdn, port and identity version. So in earlier releases it wasn’t v3 but v2.1 or something, I don’t remember exactly. The port has changed for the admin interface, it used to be 35357 for earlier versions, but as I already wrote it was deprecated. Now port 5000 is default for all three interface types (public, internal, admin), you just specify which type to use in each service section. Check out the docs to see examples.